# Mongodb query problem, how to get the matching items of the $or operator

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

Thank you for first.

MongoDB Version:4.2.11

I have a piece of data like this:

```
{
 "name":...,
 ...
 "administration" : [
    {"name":...,"job":...},
    {"name":...,"job":...}
  ],
 "shareholder" : [
    {"name":...,"proportion":...},
    {"name":...,"proportion":...},
  ]
}
```

I want to match some specified data through regular expressions:
For a example：

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$match" : 
   {
     "$or" : 
     [
       {"name" : {"$regex": "Keyword"}}
       {"administration.name": {"$regex": "Keyword"}},
       {"shareholder.name": {"$regex": "Keyword"}},
     ]
   }
  },
])
```

I want to set a flag when the **$or** operator successfully matches any condition, which is represented by a custom field, for example:`{"name" : {"$regex": "Keyword"}}`Execute on success:

```
{"$project" : 
        {
            "_id":false,
            "name" : true,
            "__regex_type__" : "name"
        }
    },
```

`{"administration.name" : {"$regex": "Keyword"}}`Execute on success:`"__regex_type__" : "administration.name"`

I try do this:

```
{"$project" : 
            {
                "_id":false,
                "name" : true,
                "__regex_type__" : 
                {
                   "$switch":
                        {
                            "branches":
                            [
                              {"case": {"$regexMatch":{"input":"$name","regex": "Keyword"}},"then" : "name"},
                              {"case": {"$regexMatch":{"input":"$administration.name","regex": "Keyword"}},"then" : "administration.name"},
                              {"case": {"$regexMatch":{"input":"$shareholder.name","regex": "Keyword"}},"then" : "shareholder.name"},
                            ],
                            "default" : "Other matches"
                        }
                }
            }
        },
```

But $regexMatch cannot match the array,I tried to use **$unwind** again, but returned the number of many array members, which did not meet my starting point.

I want to implement the same function as mysql this SQL statement in mongodb, like this:

```
SELECT name,administration.name,shareholder.name,(
 CASE
 WHEN name REGEXP("Keyword") THEN "name"
 WHEN administration.name REGEXP("Keyword") THEN "administration.name"
 WHEN shareholder.name REGEXP("Keyword") THEN "shareholder.name"
 END
)AS __regex_type__ FROM db.mytable WHERE 
  name REGEXP("Keyword") OR
  shareholder.name REGEXP("Keyword") OR
  administration.name REGEXP("Keyword");
```

Maybe this method is stupid, but I don’t have a better solution.

If you have a better solution, I would appreciate it!!!
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since $regexMatch does not handle arrays, use $filter to filter individual array elements with $regexMatch, then use $size to see how many elements matched.

```
[{"$match"=>{"$or"=>[{"a"=>"test"}, {"arr.a"=>"test"}]}},
 {"$project"=>
   {"a"=>1,
    "arr"=>1,
    "src"=>
     {"$switch"=>
       {"branches"=>
         [{"case"=>{"$regexMatch"=>{"input"=>"$a", "regex"=>"test"}},
           "then"=>"a"},
          {"case"=>
            {"$gte"=>
              [{"$size"=>
                 {"$filter"=>
                   {"input"=>"$arr.a",
                    "cond"=>
                     {"$regexMatch"=>{"input"=>"$$this", "regex"=>"test"}}}}},
               1]},
           "then"=>"arr.a"}],
        "default"=>"def"}}}}]
[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5ffb2df748966813f82f15ad'), "a"=>"test", "src"=>"a"},
 {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5ffb2df748966813f82f15ae'),
  "arr"=>[{"a"=>"test"}],
  "src"=>"arr.a"}]
```